# Image Profile not displaying correctly - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am having issues displaying my users profile images correctly. The script I have below does move an image into the correct folder and also inserts into the db correctly. The issue arises when it comes to showing it on the users profile.

I think it is something to do with my folder structure, however the moment I remove `../` in `$uploadDir` before `profiles` in the file path in the PHP script, nothing works. Any guidance would be MUCH appreciated. When I inspect element on on the image tag, you can see that the `../` is also being echoed out, which means it cannot find the image as it should only be `profiles/`.

**My folder structure:**

```
>profiles
    >image1.jpg
    >image2.jpg
>scripts
    >edit-picture.php
>profile.php
>index.php
```

**profile.php:**

```
<b>Profile Picture: </b>
    <?php 
        $picture = $row['imagePath'];
        if (empty($picture)){
            echo "<img src='profiles/no-image.png' width='100' height='100' >";
        } else {
            echo "<img src='".$row['imagePath']."' width='100' height='100' >";    
        };
    ?>
<form action="scripts/edit-picture.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" name="edit-picture" value="Upload"/>
```

**scripts/edit-picture.php:**

```
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $uploadDir = '../profiles/';

    if (isset($_POST['edit-picture'])) {

        session_start();
        $studentID = $_SESSION['studentID'];

        $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        $filePath = $uploadDir.$fileName;

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "Error uploading file";
            exit;
        }
        else{
            // If image uploads ok, return to this page
            header("Location: ../profile.php?imageuploaded");
        }
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
              printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
               $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
        } 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO `profileImage` (`imageID`, `imagePath`, `studentID`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?) ");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $filePath, $studentID); 
        $stmt->execute() or die("Failed to insert image into the database");
    }
?>
```

This is the data in the table (2nd row you can see where the error is in the `../` before the folder and image name.
[image: db]

Comment: We need to see what the SELECT query looks like, where you're pulling `$row['imagePath']` from.

Comment: A better practice is to only save the file names into the database and not the whole address. Consequently, try to eliminate '../profiles/' from the name. Then, whenever you to show the image, it will be easy to link it from anywhere in your website.

Comment: @H.M.. are you saying create a new column in the db just called name. Will this still not have the same issue as above if I done that and still set the `$uploadDir = '../profiles/';`   ?

Comment: also your going to get conflicts in names, i.e its trivial to change other peoples profile images by overwriting it, not to mention uploading .php files

Comment: @LawrenceCherone May I ask how you would avoid this, this did cross my mind and I've been searching for a decent tutorial.

Comment: @H.M.. Ok, so I have added that into my `html` code, however the issue caused now is in the php script if I delete the `../` from the variable `$uploadDir`. It can no longer find the directory. I'm so sorry, I feel like I've missed something completely obvious!?

Comment: If you want to change to the way I humbly recommended, you need to first modify the ImagePath column in your database, and then change the links. Can you tell me of your changes now?

Comment: @H.M.. Ok, changes made :) and I am now seeing images!! I just stored the name of image inside of the db, as appose to `profiles/name`, I then added in the echo statement like so: `"<img src='profiles/".$row['imagePath']."' width='100' height='100' >";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice to save the directory addresses in your database. For your images, you just need to save a name, for example abc.jpg, and not 'directory/abc.jpg'. The logic behind this is clear, you might need to link to images from different pages in your website. If you add the directories in your database, it will be really hard, though not imossible to link to the images and show them.
Consequently, try to eliminate '../profiles/' from the name. Then, whenever you want to show the image, it will be easy to link it from anywhere in your website.
So, just omit the following block:

```
    $uploadDir = '../profiles/';
```

and change your **$filepath** like the following:

```
$filePath = md5($file_name . microtime()) . substr($fileName , -5, 5);
```

This has two benefits. The filenames will never ever be overwritten, and then, for the sake of a simple layer of security, the students will not be identifiable by the file names.

Then, when you want to link to the image in your **edit-picture.php**, you will write

```
"<img src='../profiles/".$row['imagePath']."' width='100' height='100' >"
```

and when you want to link to the image from your **profile.php**, you will write:

```
"<img src='profiles/".$row['imagePath']."' width='100' height='100' >"
```

By the way, in your php code, you are using **get_magic_quotes_gpc**. First of all, it is not a good practice, then try to keep your php version always updated.
Php Official website, regarding get_magic_quotes_gpc says:

> Warning
> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Try to use other php security functions. Good Luck.